# s3_direct_upload getting TypeError

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This line of code:

```
= s3_uploader_form callback_url: dispute_documents_url(@dispute.id), callback_param: "dispute_document[remote_file_url]", id: "s3_uploader" do
```

is getting a no implicit conversion of nil into String error.  Removing the whole thing results in no error, but removing any/all of the options still gives the error.